# Distribute Java jar application in Optical Disk

Tags: bundle, java, executable-jar, dvd

I am trying to ship my Jar application using DVDs and need the user just to run an exe and launch the program. So I have written a batch file which runs the jar using the private JRE shipped in the same DVD.

Now when I run the batch file from the DVD it takes over one minute to launch the application because JRE is in the DVD as well.

When I copy the JRE in hard disk and use that in my batch file to lauch the program it runs fast. However I wouldn't the path where the user copies the JRE in his hard disk. How would I detect the same in my batch file ?

Comment: Which OS are you running on, does the solution need to be platform generic?

Comment: Upvoted as I expect this is a common issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution to your problem is to use a Java application installer, and to put the installer on the DVD. Some Java application installers include the ability to bundle a JRE, for instance [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I think you mean installer would copy the jre and program to hard disk during installation. But I need the jar and related resource to stay in the DVD itself only the jre to be in the hard disk for better launching time

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'd suggest updating your batch script to look for JAVA_HOME. If present and equal or newer to the version you are running, then use that JRE instead.

See the following blog for instructions on how to do this.
http://www2.hawaii.edu/~sdunan/study_guides/ics211/WindowsCommandLineCompiling.html

Comment: I'll add some sample code if I get time to come back to this question, meanwhile I thought I'd give you an path to start to follow.

Comment: Thanks but what if JAVA_HOME is not set. it would start using the jre in DVD and slow down. Anyway to make sure JAVA home is set to begin with ? May be 1st time if Java home is not set it copies to jre to C drive and then next time onwards it launches using the same Java home? What do you suggest

Comment: You could do this, or you could include the jre installer, and launch that instead

Comment: Thanks for the link, would the jre installer set the JAVA_HOME ? I was wondering what would my batch file know where the user copies the JRE in his local disk

Comment: If you launch the installer, you can test to see if it installed to the default location. 99% of users will install to the default location. However this assumes your user has administration access to their workstation.

Comment: by Default location you mean "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0" ?

Comment: Finally I settled with Launch4J , I think it tried to look for the defaults paths.

Comment: Cool, please post how that went as I have not used Launch4J, and if successful flag the answer by @GrayBeardedGeek as correct.

Comment: Thanks but I was using Launch4J even before asking the question. I am still not able to launch the program immediately from DVD. I had no other choice and settled with Launch4J just to bring up a splash screen till the program launches after 3 minutes. Which is tool long wait. I am marked GrayBeardedGeek's answer useful.